# How can I fix this error: Parameter index out of range

Tags: java, sql, database

I am working on a registration page, and I can't seem to solve this issue regarding SQL.

Error message

> Parameter index out of range (1 < number of parameters, which is 0)

any help would be appreciated

```
try{
    String query = "INSERT INTO `Registration`(`ID`, `First Name`, `Second Name`, `email`, `account_type`, `Post code`, `Town`, `Address`, `Phone number`, `Organisation`, `Website`, `Username`, `Password`, `Payment Method`) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')";

con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/globalmusic","root", "");

pst = con.prepareStatement(query);              
pst.setString(1, txtAnumber.getText());              
pst.setString(2, txtFname.getText());               
pst.setString(3, txtLname.getText());               
pst.setString(4, txtEaddress.getText());                
pst.setString(5, cmbAtype.getSelectedItem().toString());               
pst.setString(6, txtPcode.getText());                
pst.setString(7, txtTown.getText());                
pst.setString(8, txtAddress.getText());                
pst.setString(9, txtPnumber.getText());               
pst.setString(10, txtOrg.getText());                
pst.setString(11, txtWaddress.getText());              
pst.setString(12, txtUname.getText());               
pst.setString(13, txtPass.getText());             
pst.setString(14, cmbPmethod.getSelectedItem().toString());          
pst.executeUpdate();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registration successful");

} catch(Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Remove single quotes around the question mark in the `VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')` and try

Answer (score 0):

You must not have quotes for the placeholder parameters. Must be like this:

```
"INSERT INTO Registration(ID, First Name, Second Name, email, account_type, Post code, Town, Address, Phone number, Organisation, Website, Username, Password, Payment Method) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

Comment: I would rather say “you must not have quotes” since that is the issue, this reads too much of a “you can but don’t need”